# huggingface transformers convert logit scores to probability

Tags: python, text-classification, bert-language-model, multilabel-classification, huggingface-transformers

I'm a beginner to this field and am stuck. I am following this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-multi-class-text-classification-with-bert-transformer-and-keras-c6355eccb63a) to build a multi-label classification using huggingface tranformers.

Following is the code I'm using to train my model.

```
# Name of the BERT model to use
model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'
# Max length of tokens
max_length = 100

PATH = 'uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/'

# Load transformers config and set output_hidden_states to False
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(PATH)
config.output_hidden_states = False

# Load BERT tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(PATH, local_files_only=True, config = config)
# tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH, local_files_only=True, config = config)

# Load the Transformers BERT model
transformer_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(PATH, config = config,from_pt=True)

#######################################
### ------- Build the model ------- ###

# Load the MainLayer
bert = transformer_model.layers[0]

# Build your model input
input_ids = Input(shape=(None,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
# attention_mask = Input(shape=(max_length,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32') 
# inputs = {'input_ids': input_ids, 'attention_mask': attention_mask}
inputs = {'input_ids': input_ids}

# Load the Transformers BERT model as a layer in a Keras model
bert_model = bert(inputs)[1]
dropout = Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob, name='pooled_output')
pooled_output = dropout(bert_model, training=False)


# Then build your model output
issue = Dense(units=len(data.U_label.value_counts()), kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=config.initializer_range), name='issue')(pooled_output)
outputs = {'issue': issue}

# And combine it all in a model object
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='BERT_MultiLabel_MultiClass')

# Take a look at the model
model.summary()


#######################################
### ------- Train the model ------- ###

# Set an optimizer
optimizer = Adam(
    learning_rate=5e-05,
    epsilon=1e-08,
    decay=0.01,
    clipnorm=1.0)

# Set loss and metrics
loss = {'issue': CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True)}
# loss = {'issue': CategoricalCrossentropy()}
metric = {'issue': CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')}

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer = optimizer,
    loss = loss, 
    metrics = metric)

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data['U_H_Label'])

# Ready output data for the model
y_issue = to_categorical(le.transform(data['U_H_Label']))

# Tokenize the input (takes some time)
x = tokenizer(
    text=data['Input_Data'].to_list(),
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length=max_length,
    truncation=True,
    padding=True, 
    return_tensors='tf',
    return_token_type_ids = False,
    return_attention_mask = True,
    verbose = True)

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(
    # x={'input_ids': x['input_ids'], 'attention_mask': x['attention_mask']},
    x={'input_ids': x['input_ids']},
    y={'issue': y_issue},
    validation_split=0.2,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=10)
```

When I use the model.predict() function, I think I get logit scores for each class, and would like to convert them to probability scores ranging from 0 to 1.

I have read in multiple blogs that a softmax function is what I have to use, but am not able to relate on where and how. If anyone could please tell me what line of code would be required, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Are you trying for multi-label classification or multi-class classification?

Comment: Multi-label classification

Comment: You have to use sigmoid activations, and also Binary cross entropy as the loss function.

Comment: Could you help where in the code I have to add the sigmoid activation function? Will making the activation function in the last dense layer do it? 

Thanks for pointing out the loss function, I'll be sure to change it.

Comment: Yes, you have to add sigmoid after the last Dense Layer

Comment: Being a beginner, I'm still stuck at how to do that. issue = Dense(units=len(data.U_label.value_counts()), kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=config.initializer_range), name='issue',activation="sigmoid")(pooled_output)
Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the logit scores from model.predict(), then you can do as follows:

```
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torch

# convert logit score to torch array
torch_logits = torch.from_numpy(logit_score)

# get probabilities using softmax from logit score and convert it to numpy array
probabilities_scores = F.softmax(torch_logits, dim = -1).numpy()[0]
```